# Database data modeler application

Tags: software-recommendation, database

Is there some application for creating database data model diagrams that is able to generate SQL expressions which will create the database schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few:

- [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/provides/dbmodeling.jsp),
- [MySQL WorkBench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/),
- [fabForce designer](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/screenshots.php),
- [SQL developer](http://sqldeveloper.solyp.com/index.html)
- [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html)

good luck